# Swift: Copy Information Selected by User in ABPersonViewController to Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller, abrecord

I'm trying to implement the `func personViewController(personViewController: ABPersonViewController!,
        shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson person: ABRecord!,
        property property: ABPropertyID,
        identifier valueIdentifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool` function, which is part of the `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate` protocol and is called whenever the user clicks on an item in the `ABPersonViewController`, such that any information the user selects will be copied to a `[String : String]` dictionary such that the property name will be the key for the property value: `[..."kABPersonFirstNameProperty" : "Alexander"...]`, say.

I also want to avoid a switch or a long list of conditions testing for if a property is this or that; I'd rather handle it as generally as possible—I'm trying for only two different cases: if the property is a single value or a multi value. If it's a multi-value, I'd like to copy down all the information available.

For example, if the user clicks on the address, the result might be such: `[..."kABPersonAddressStreetKey" : "1 Infinite Loop", "kABPersonAddressCityKey" : "Cupertino" , "kABPersonAddressStateKey", "California (or CA?)"...]`.

This is all I have, after various hours of scouring the Apple Developer Library and related SO questions (pathetic, I know):

```
func personViewController(personViewController: ABPersonViewController!,
    shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson person: ABRecord!,
    property property: ABPropertyID,
    identifier valueIdentifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool {

    s["kABPersonFirstNameProperty"] = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) as! String //the name can't actually be selected by the user, but I want to capture it anyway
    s["kABPersonLastNameProperty"] = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty) as! String

    if valueIdentifier == 0 { //property is a single property, not a multivalue property

        let record = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property)
        s[property as! String!] = record as! String

    } else { //property is an ABMultiValue

        let multiRecord = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property) as! ABMultiValueRef
        s[property as! String] = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiRecord, valueIdentifier)

    }

    return false

}
```

I can tell there are plenty of pieces missing—is it even possible to condense this into a dictionary?

Thanks in advance (and 100 reputation to whomever provides a complete, correct answer).

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for too... Apple resources seem sparse (and Objective-C-y) when it comes to the AB world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vadian's answer as a starting point, I compiled the following, which will gather and copy to a dictionary almost all of the information a user can select (and some information which a user can't click on—first name, last name, organization—automatically).

It's a work in progress, which I'll update as I continue to add support for more properties, but at present it works for first name, last name, email, phone numbers, address, and some social profiles.

I had to use indirect methods in some cases: storing phone numbers whose labels didn't have a designated key as `kAB_Label`s, for example, and it doesn't yet take the label of an email address.

With `s` as of type `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`, here it is:

```
func personViewController(personViewController: ABPersonViewController!, shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool {

    addPropertyForKey("kABPersonFirstNameProperty", person : person, property: kABPersonFirstNameProperty)
    addPropertyForKey("kABPersonLastNameProperty", person : person, property: kABPersonLastNameProperty)
    addPropertyForKey("kABPersonOrganizationProperty", person: person, property: kABPersonOrganizationProperty)

    if (property == kABPersonAddressProperty) {
        let multiRecord : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeUnretainedValue()
        let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiRecord, identifier)
        let addressRecord :AnyObject = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRecord, index).takeUnretainedValue()
        addValuesFromRecord(addressRecord, forKeys:["Street", "City", "State", "ZIP", "Country", "CountryCode"])

    }

    if (property == kABPersonEmailProperty) {

        let multiRecord: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeUnretainedValue()
        let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiRecord, identifier)
        let email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRecord, index).takeUnretainedValue() as! String

        if (s["kABPersonEmailProperty(1)"] == nil) {

            s["kABPersonEmailProperty(1)"] = email

        } else {

            s["kABPersonEmailProperty(2)"] = email

        }

    }

    if (property == kABPersonSocialProfileProperty) {

        let multiRecord: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeUnretainedValue()
        let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiRecord, identifier)
        let profile = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRecord, index).takeUnretainedValue()
        let profileType = profile["service"] as! String
        let profileName = profile["username"] as! String

        switch profileType {
            case "facebook" : s["kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook"] = profileName
            case  "twitter" : s["kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter"] = profileName
            case "sinaweibo": s["kABPersonSocialProfileServiceSinaWeibo"] = profileName
            default: break
        }



    }

    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {

        let multiRecord : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeUnretainedValue()
        let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiRecord, identifier)
        let number = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRecord, index).takeUnretainedValue() as! String

        let locLabel: CFStringRef = (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiRecord, index) != nil) ? ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiRecord, index).takeUnretainedValue() as CFStringRef : ""
        let customLabel = String (stringInterpolationSegment: ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel))

        var cfStr:CFTypeRef = locLabel
        var nsTypeString = cfStr as! NSString
        var a:String = nsTypeString as String

        var b = a

        if (a.rangeOfString("_$!<") != nil) {

            b = a.substringFromIndex(a.rangeOfString("_$!<")!.endIndex)

            b = b.substringToIndex(b.rangeOfString(">!$_")!.startIndex)

        }

        switch b {

        case "Mobile" : s["kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel"] = number
        case "iPhone" : s["kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel"] = number
        case "Main" : s["kABPersonPhoneMainLabel"] = number
        case "Home" : s["kABHomeLabel"] = number
        case "Work" : s["kABWorkLabel"] = number
        case "Other" : s["kABOtherLabel"] = number
        default: break

        }

    }

    println(s)

    return false
}
```

Please, anyone should feel free to copy any/all parts of it which would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there can't be a generic method to retrieve information from AddressBook because there are too many different collection and property types.

This is an example to get `first name`, `last name` and `address` information when the user taps on an address field.

It's assumed that the dictionary `s` is declared as

```
var s = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

---

```
 func personViewController(personViewController: ABPersonViewController!, shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool {

    addPropertyForKey("FirstName", person : person, property: kABPersonFirstNameProperty)
    addPropertyForKey("LastName", person : person, property: kABPersonLastNameProperty)

    if (property == kABPersonAddressProperty) {
      let multiRecord : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeUnretainedValue()
      let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiRecord, identifier)
      let addressRecord :AnyObject = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRecord, index).takeUnretainedValue()
      addValuesFromRecord(addressRecord, forKeys:["Street", "City", "State", "ZIP", "Country", "CountryCode"])

      println(s)
    }

    return false
  }

  func addPropertyForKey(key : String, person: ABRecord, property : ABPropertyID)
  {
    let value : AnyObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeUnretainedValue()
    s[key] = value
  }

  func addValuesFromRecord(record : AnyObject,  forKeys keys : [String])
  {
    for key in keys {
      if let value : AnyObject = record[key] {
        s[key] = value
      }
    }
  }
```

to be as generic as possible, all values are declared as `AnyObject`