# Optional Type 'String??' Not Unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, option-type, optional-parameters

"Value of optional type 'String??' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" -

I got this weird compiler error today, which was entirely confusing due to the **two** question marks after `String`.

I have a dictionary `s`, of type `[String : String?]`, and a function which accepts all arguments as `String?`s. Specifically (from 5813's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822329/swift-copy-information-selected-by-user-in-abpersonviewcontroller-to-dictionary) of copying user-selected information into a dictionary), I have an elaborated version of the following:

```
func combine(firstname: String?, lastname: String?) {...}

var text = combine(s["kABPersonFirstNameProperty"], lastname: s["kABPersonLastNameProperty"])
```

I'm getting the error on the second line, and I'm wondering why it's so. If the values in `s` are of type `String?`, shouldn't that  be accepted by `combine()`, since it's arguments are supposed to be of the same type? Why, then, would I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dictionary<T1, T2>[key]` returns `T2?`. This is to return nil in case key doesn't exist.

So if T2 is `String?`, `s[key]` returns `String??`
You cannot pass `String??` as `String?`

You can call like this to unwrap and prepare for non-existing key as well

```
var text = combine(s["kABPersonFirstNameProperty"] ?? nil, lastname: s["kABPersonLastNameProperty"] ?? nil)
```

By the way, code below will not set value to nil but remove the entire entry from the dictionary

```
s[key] = nil
```

If you want the value to be nil instead of removing entry, you will have to do this

```
s[key] = nil as String?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. So, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: When I try `as String?`, I get a message that says "'String??' is not convertible to 'String?'".

Comment: Please see my revised answer again :)

Answer (score 2):

It is once optional because your dictionary value is optional. And it is optional again, because dictionary[key] returns optional. So you need to unwrap it twice.

Try this in a playground to understand the problem (and see possible solution):

```
let oos: String?? = "Hello"
print(oos)

if let os = oos { // Make String?
    print(os)
    if let s = os { // Make ordinary String
        print(s)
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
 Optional(Optional("Hello"))

 Optional("Hello")

 Hello
```

But you could use other ways than if let to unwrap, too. For example:

```
 print(oos! ?? "n/a")
```

Will force unwrap it once and then print either the inner String or n/a in case of nil...

Comment: HI MirekE, thanks for the quick response. The values of the dictionary will, at times, be `nil`, so what marks should I use, and where? I can't use the `!` because it might not have a value, and I tried `s[key]??`, but got another error.

Comment: There are many options, for example you can use `if let` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest solution would be to make the dictionary hold `String` instead of `String?`. Then you don't have the unwrapping problems which are described in other solutions.

Or do you really have to store `String?` types?
Do you want to differentiate between 'key exists but holds nil' and 'key does not exist'?

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to supply different logic meanings to both "value not exist" and "nil value exists"

Comment: @hebinda: Sure, but that should be an explicit decision. I have the impression that @Randoms really wanted a `[String : String]` instead of a `[String : String?]`.